# HTTPS to Imgur?

Tags: discussion, images

Should we use HTTP image links,

[image: HTTP Sample],

or HTTPS,

[image: HTTPS Sample]?

My argument for HTTPS is that it works both on HTTP and HTTPS pages.

Addendum: my high internet moats off almost all HTTPS except for Google etc. I have to use Tor on my laptop to accomplish anything at all.

---

**What if Markdown could support `//i.imgur.com/` links?**

Here's a really bad workaround:

```
<a href="//i.stack.imgur.com/CvnuZ.png"><img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/CvnuZ.png"></a>
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for using HTTPS links and SO should be HTTPS too

Answer (score 2):

For people who can't wait, just use a plugin like [HTTPSEverywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere%20) and supply it with a rule like:

```
<ruleset name="i.stack.imgur.com">
  <target host="imgur.com"/>
  <target host="i.imgur.com"/>
  <target host="i.stack.imgur.com"/>
</ruleset>
```

PS: Markdown already supports `//`-urls.

Answer (score 1):

Both `i.imgur.com` and `i.stack.imgur.com` support HTTPS. But HTTPS is still in an odd phase around here and I think still isn't officially supported yet, even though it does work (most of the time).

But when you embed an image using the 'Insert Image' button in the editor, it still uses `http://` to embed it. Stack Exchange could easily make the change to the editor to HTTPS once they are ready to make a larger switch to HTTPS.

And when the MSO/MSE switch happened, Stack Exchange updated all the links from `meta.stackoverflow.com` to `meta.stackexchange.com` across the entire site. So I would imagine once the HTTPS boat finally sails, they would do a mass update across all posts that would move all images over to HTTPS.

Long story short, if you feel like putting `https://` in your image URLs, awesome. But I think it's perfectly fine to continue with `http://`.

Comment: now it should be `https`: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time?cb=1

Answer (score -5):

As Steven V said, use `http` unless you want to feel really good about yourself. Until it happens for everybody, let's wait for someone smart to write a Userscript to do it for us.

Comment: If we wait nothing happens, HTTPS should be default everywhere.