# Default to HTTPS links when using imgur links

Tags: feature-request, images, ssl

I use the HTTPS Everywhere extension, and Chrome shows the security warning below:

[image: HTTPS Everywhere security warning]

If you open the browser console you'll see that the culprit are imgur links.

What is the [state of HTTPS support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270602/https-www-stackoverflow-com-redirects-to-insecure-http-stackoverflow-com)? A previous question shows we can [switch to HTTPS for imgur links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261600/https-to-imgur).

If this is to be implemented, I see two action items at least:

1. Set the https scheme for all imgur links served by SE sites; e.g. the links to the user's profile.
2. Set the https scheme for the link created when pasting images.

Comment: This is fixed in the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch), I would highly recommend using it.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to forget about https for a while, while we focus on StackEgg...