# Should flair provide HTTPS links by default?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, ssl, flair

I have seen [default to HTTPS links when using Imgur links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284129/default-to-https-links-when-using-imgur-links), [https://www.stackoverflow.com redirects to insecure http://stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270602/https-www-stackoverflow-com-redirects-to-insecure-http-stackoverflow-com) and [HTTPS to Imgur?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261600/https-to-imgur), but none of them really capture my question, which is:

When I grab the HTML to embed my flair should the links included (both the one to my profile and the one for the image) be given as HTTPS?

I noticed that they were not HTTPS when I embedded my flair on the [new blog](https://ilovetux.github.io) that I'm starting on [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/). Since I can access the web page over HTTP or HTTPS, I prefer HTTPS (as arguably everyone should nowadays) and provide links with the HTTPS scheme specified, but when I added my flair the reaffirming lock icon (in my Firefox URL bar) turned into an [alarming warning triangle](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-tell-if-my-connection-is-secure#w_gray-warning-triangle).

After I noticed this issue, I tried to change them to HTTPS and was somewhat surprisingly they worked. Then I immediately thought to myself: Shouldn't this be the default?

Perhaps I am wrong, but it feels as though if it's provided we should use it.

As Deduplicator mentioned below I now believe that the provided URLs should be made protocol relative.

I hate to sound "flip-floppy", but after seeing the comments and answer below, I gave it a ton of though and I'm going back to my original opinion that we should use HTTPS by default.

Comment: Well, arguably the default should be protocol-relative URLs, as the SE sites all have http *and* https working good enough, at least for that.

Comment: Now that you mention that I completely agree. protocol relative URLs would be perfect, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Protocol relative URLs are no longer considered best practise, for example, [Paul Irish no longer recommends protocol relative URLs](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) and considers it an anti-pattern. Just always use HTTPS.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, it should be provided over HTTPS.

Using an `http://` link breaks when you decide to upgrade your site to HTTPS, and it's insecure.

Using a protocol relative URL `//` is [no longer recommended by people like Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/), because it's vulnerable to a man-on-the-side attack when served in an HTTP page. Nowadays, just always use HTTPS.

Comment: `Nowadays, just always use HTTPS`. I wish our clients heeded this advice! :P

Comment: I wish certificates would be cheaper!

Comment: @deW1 Certificates from Let's Encrypt are free.

Comment: @Flimm you're amazing thank you :)